# Protégé - How can I rename an object property?

Tags: protege, protege4

After created, an object property, seemingly, can't be renamed. Is it a Protégé's feature? If it is possible, how can I do that? It is a very annoying process to remove the property and add the another renamed one. I am using Protégé 4.3.0.

Comment: in short : Ctrl+U

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The process is the same as renaming other types of entities. Say you've got a property:

[image]

Then you can select it, then select in the menu *Refactor > Rename Entity* and you'll get a renaming dialog:

[image]

and you can enter a new name:

[image]

and there it is:

[image]